# Is it possible to use Git with TFS is the users don't have a TFS account?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to know if it is possible to use Git with TFS if two users don't have a Visual Studio account/subscription?

This because, our company can't give them a company email because they are outsourcing and they have the project in a separate server and as a request of our boss we need to have all of our projects in the same place.

Is this possible or as an ultimate instance, do we need to give them an email just so they can work with our repository in TFS?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: what does having an email have to do with TFS?  Do you mean ***domain account***?  Or are you referring to https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/ ?

Comment: You ask about license or access? In the former case read the Visual Studio 2015 Licensing White Paper https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350

Comment: @Kritner We are using visual studio online, so in our VS we use our user to log in and work with TFS, and as I said in the post, we cannot give them and email of the company (boss reasons), so we are having trouble to figure out how to work with them if they cannot have access to TFS without an email.

Comment: @GiulioVian I am going to check it out to see if there is something that can clear this out for me, thanks for the link.

Comment: if you're using VSO (TFS Online), they don't need to have a company email, they just need to have ***an*** email.  Unless you're using some sort of AD integration with your VSO.  You should just be able to add any microsoft account as a contributor to a project

Comment: Note that TFS and VSO are different things, and have different tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the section **Which email addresses can I add?** on [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#add-users-to-your-visual-studio-team-services-account):

You must add email addresses for ["personal" Microsoft accounts](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/default.aspx) unless your Team Services account [uses your organization's directory](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#ConnectedDirectory) to authenticate users and control account access through [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis). If your users don't have Microsoft accounts, have them [sign up](https://account.microsoft.com/?lang=en-US&refd=account.live.com&refp=landing).

If your Team Services account is connected to your organization's directory, all users must be directory members and sign in to Team Services with "work or school accounts" that are managed by your organization's directory. If they're not members, have a directory administrator add them to the directory. That way, you can find them in this directory when you add users by searching for their email addresses or display names.